# uncontrolled <select> default value in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How does one set the default value of an uncontrolled `<select>` in a JSX stanza? I have many controlled `<select>`'s in flight, I know the difference.

```
<select
  // defaultValue="Select a type"
  // value="Select a type"
  onChange={ this.handleTypeSelect.bind(this, event) }
>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a type</option>
  <option value="type1">type1</option>
  <option value="type2">type2</option>
</select>
```

Running the code above *as-is* generates the dreaded:

`Warning: Use the defaultValue or value props on <select> instead of setting`selected`on <option>`

Removing the `selected` line and uncommenting the `value` or `defaultValue` lines removes the console warning but has no effect in the browser at all (as in the default value does not show up).

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`defaultValue` takes the value of the default option you want selected. Your option *Select a type* has no value.

If you do `<option value="-1">Select a type</option>` then `defaultValue={-1}` it should work.

```
<select defaultValue={-1} onChange={ this.handleTypeSelect.bind(this, event)}>
    <option value="-1" disabled>Select a type</option>
    <option value="type1">type1</option>
    <option value="type2">type2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow that's just about as clear as concrete, but thanks. Your explanation is clear, but the concept is/was not. By way of clarification ;-)

Comment: Answer assumes you are forced to do an action in the onChange Handler; sometimes you may just want to change the dropdown, and click some button later.